# How to use locking to prevent same stored procedure transaction from multiple user in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, security, stored-procedures, transactions

I want know how to use locking to prevent same stored procedure transaction from multiple user in SQL Server?

I have many books and each book have 1 to 100 serial numbers.

And I wrote a stored procedure with transactions to insert data into the main table and each transaction update the booktable with serial number like 1,2,3...100 and assigns number to each user like I have book of number 1.

**Book/SerialNo**

- User1 has 1/1
- User2 has = 1/2
- ....
- User100 has 1/100

Multiple users will use this application.

So I don't want to repeat serial number of a particular book like

```
User1 has 1/1
User2 has 1/2
user3 has 1/2
user4 has 1/3
```

I have multiple transaction T1, T2, T3... at same time and using same procedure. To insert data into main table and update book serial number..

Now I want to know how to protect or lock transactions. Until T1 is not complete their task .. T2 on hold and then T2 is not complete their task ..T3 on hold..

Please provide me the best solution or example.

Comment: what does one by one mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to figure out what your problem actually is, but I would assume you need something like this:

```
declare @serialNo

update top(1) Books
set 
  @serialNo = serialNo, 
  status = 'R',
  user = @userId
where 
  book = @bookId and 
  status = 'F'
```

This assumes you have a status (Free / Reserved) and you want to pick one of them for the user.

Comment: Actually the problem is  when transaction-1 and transaction-2 have same book number and serial number like
T1 =  1/1
T2 =  1/1

than how to stop to insert duplicate value at same time.

Comment: @Rohit The serial number is coming from the table, and since it requires the value of  status to be 'F', those transactions will not get the same serialNo.